# initialized variable doesn't change?

Tags: java

Getting caught up on why this works. The variable `biggest` is initialized with a counter that starts at index 0 from the array list which is value of `3`. but when compared in the while loop it compares 3 whether 3 is more than 3 if not counter goes up. `counter` goes up but the initialized "biggest" variable remains the same. Why?

```
 public static int greatest(ArrayList<Integer> list) {
        System.out.println(list); 
        int counter = 0;

        int biggest = list.get(counter); // biggest starts at index 0 - value 3 // this counter seems to go up but the "biggest"
                                        // value remains the same when the counter below goes up.

        while (counter< list.size() ){// goes to while loop
            if ( list.get(counter)>biggest){
                biggest=list.get(counter);
            }

            counter++;
        }

        System.out.println(biggest);
        System.out.print(counter);  
        return biggest;   
    }            

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<Integer> lista = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        lista.add(3);
        lista.add(2);
        lista.add(71);
        lista.add(2);

        System.out.println("The greatest number is: " + greatest(lista));
    }
```

Comment: Unable to reproduce. I get output `[3, 2, 71, 2]`, `71`, `4The greatest number is: 71`. In short, the `biggest` variable did not remain the same, in the loop iteration where `counter` is 2.

Comment: The code works but the OP cannot understand why.

Comment: @Pitto exactly. Nevertheless, the OP already got a bunch of downvotes... (sigh)

Comment: @Andrew Tobilko I mean if you hover over the downvote, the text perfectly describes this question, especially before the edit to remove the whitespace.  The question is not clear at all, and he only needed to research how an `if` statement functions.

Comment: The ability to focus while read seems to be a rare quality. I am just surprised that among programmes many people simply do not parse text properly (including myself, clearly).

Comment: @Nexevis It is also probably the OP's first (or second) question and he/she is clearly inexperienced. We've all been there, right?

Comment: @Pitto Right, but you cannot blame people for using website functions how it was made to be.  Note that I do not have it downvoted.

Comment: @Nexevis You are indeed right. But it is our duty to make SO not only efficient but also a welcoming and nice place to stay, imho.

Comment: @Pitto Trust me I agree with you, I only started actually contributing to this website a few months ago, and I already _knew_ how to program and it was still a learning curve.  SO is the opposite of welcoming.

Comment: @Nexevis Many questions are just garbage and "do my homeworks" and in that case I do understand the hard line. Other questions just show that people don't have enough experience or knowledge - even in simply asking a good question sometimes. I always try to be the guy/gal I wish I had found when I began. Also today I happen to ask the silliest questions on the planet in the eyes of better programmers... Life is a circle :)

Comment: Hi Lin S.
Did you have time to read my answer?
In case it was useful please remember to upvote it and/or choose it as final answer for your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The biggest variable changes only if the current value in the loop is bigger than the value currently stored in biggest.

```
list.get(counter)>biggest
```

This is the reason why you don't see it always changing.

I've added a couple of prints to better show this concept, hoping you can use it for better understanding.

```
 public static int greatest(ArrayList<Integer> list) {
        System.out.println(list); 
        int counter = 0;

        int biggest = list.get(counter); // biggest starts at index 0 - value 3 // this counter seems to go up but the "biggest"
                                        // value remains the same when the counter below goes up.

        while (counter< list.size() ){// goes to while loop
            System.out.println("Current biggest value: " + biggest);
            System.out.println("Current iteration value: " + list.get(counter));
            if ( list.get(counter)>biggest){
                System.out.println("Current value is bigger than biggest! Changing biggest value...");
                biggest=list.get(counter);
            }

            counter++;
        }

        System.out.println(biggest);
        System.out.print(counter);  
        return biggest;   
    }            

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<Integer> lista = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        lista.add(3);
        lista.add(2);
        lista.add(71);
        lista.add(2);

        System.out.println("The greatest number is: " + greatest(lista));
    }
```

As a bonus I also want to share another version done with an arguably simpler for loop.

Note how here the value of max is set as the minimum possible value that an integer can have on purpose.

Doing so we can be sure that is will be surely lower of any other value found in the ArrayList.

Here's the example:

```
public int getMax(ArrayList<Integer> list){
    int max = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
    for(int i=0; i<list.size(); i++){
        if(list.get(i) > max){
            max = list.get(i);
        }
    }
    return max;
}
```

Comment: @Nexevis Very good point! Thanks for the correction, I've updated my answer.